# Getting summation an element of an array of a specific element

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

ARRAY 1

```
{
  parent: 'parent 1',
  occupiedStock: 0,
  sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-1',
  shop: 'Remax Online'
}
{
  parent: 'parent 2',
  occupiedStock: 1,
  sku: 'API-TEST-PRODUCT-DO-NOT-USE-1',
  shop: 'Zealer Tech'
}
{
  parent: 'parent 2',
  occupiedStock: 2,
  sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-5',
  shop: 'Remax Online'
}
{
  parent: 'parent 1',
  occupiedStock: 0,
  sku: '1591630793-1609218546440-0',
  shop: 'Remax Online'
}
{
  parent: 'parent 2',
  occupiedStock: 0,
  sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-6',
  shop: 'Remax Online'
}
{
  parent: 'parent 1',
  occupiedStock: 1,
  sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-8',
  shop: 'Remax Online'
}
{
  parent: 'parent 1',
  occupiedStock: 0,
  sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-9',
  shop: 'Remax Online'
}
{
  parent: 'parent 2',
  occupiedStock: 2,
  sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-7',
  shop: 'Remax Online'
}
```

I need to make an array that would make a summation of parent's occupied stock, ideally the new array would look like:

ARRAY 2

```
{
  parent: 'parent 1',
  totalOccupiedStock: 1,
}
{
  parent: 'parent 2',
  totalOccupiedStock: 5,
}
```

What's the best approach to merge occupied stocks of parents...

my post I guess are mostly codes, and I cannot proceed to post this question. I hope this is enough :)

Comment: _my post I guess are mostly codes_ - You didn't post a single line of code

Comment: Are you trying to copy that array and remove `sku` and `shop` fields from each object in it?

Comment: @VelrinBlack, yes. and getting the summation of occupied stock of each parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. Traverse the array and make parent as key and based on that key sum the `occupiedStock`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    parent: 'parent 1',
    occupiedStock: 0,
    sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-1',
    shop: 'Remax Online',
  },
  {
    parent: 'parent 2',
    occupiedStock: 1,
    sku: 'API-TEST-PRODUCT-DO-NOT-USE-1',
    shop: 'Zealer Tech',
  },
  {
    parent: 'parent 2',
    occupiedStock: 2,
    sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-5',
    shop: 'Remax Online',
  },
  {
    parent: 'parent 1',
    occupiedStock: 0,
    sku: '1591630793-1609218546440-0',
    shop: 'Remax Online',
  },
  {
    parent: 'parent 2',
    occupiedStock: 0,
    sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-6',
    shop: 'Remax Online',
  },
  {
    parent: 'parent 1',
    occupiedStock: 1,
    sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-8',
    shop: 'Remax Online',
  },
  {
    parent: 'parent 1',
    occupiedStock: 0,
    sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-9',
    shop: 'Remax Online',
  },
  {
    parent: 'parent 2',
    occupiedStock: 2,
    sku: 'api-create-product-test-sample-7',
    shop: 'Remax Online',
  },
];

const ret = Object.values(
  data.reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    const key = c.parent;
    p[key] = p[key] ?? { parent: c.parent, occupiedStock: 0 };
    p[key].occupiedStock += c.occupiedStock;
    return p;
  }, {})
);
console.log(ret);
```